# R to SQL Server Connection via JDBC - wrong version of driver

Tags: java, r, sql-server, jdbc, rjava

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server via JDBC (yes, I know ODBC is better, but I'd need to make changes to the server security do to that).

```
  library(RJDBC)
  library(rJava)
  drv <- JDBC("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" , 
              "C:/SQL JDBC/sqljdbc_4.1/enu/jre7/sqljdbc41.jar" ,identifier.quote="`")
```

But I can't seem to find the right version of the driver:

```
Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : 
  java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriver has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 58.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

I've tried with drivers for 4.0, 4.1, 4.2, and 8.4:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server-support-matrix?view=sql-server-ver15#java-and-jdbc-specification-support

I have 64-bit R and 64-bit Java installed on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have Java 8 installed on your machine, but Driver was build for java 14 (*class file version 58.0* tells that).

You can either install java 14 on your machine or get a JDBC driver for Java 8.

[A link for SQL Server JDBC driver for java 8](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/microsoft/sqlserver/mssql-jdbc/8.4.0.jre8/mssql-jdbc-8.4.0.jre8.jar)

Comment: Thanks for updating the link. Unfortunately, I get the same error even with the new driver you linked to (mssql-jdbc-8.4.0.jre8.jar)

Comment: Maybe a stupid question but did you update your `JDBC` classpath parameter so it is the path to a new jar?

Comment: Not a stupid question since that was my problem. Restarting the R session clears whatever variable was cached.

Comment: Now on to the next step. Connecting using dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:sqlserver://ServerName;databaseName=DBname") gives this error:

```Error in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", as.character(url)[1],  : 
  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host TPS-db2, port 1433 has failed. Error: "TPS-db2. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".```

Comment: It could be one of three problems:
1. The host TPS-db2 is down or is not reachable (try `ping TPS-db2` to check if it is reachable)
2. Firewall on TPS-db2 blocks your connection to port 1433
3. SQL Server on TPS-db2 is not configured properly. In this case, you can take a look at this manual: https://docs.sdl.com/801922/570899/sdl-tridion-docs-13-sp2/microsoft-sql-server-ports